# styles.css and scripts.js files not loading under CNAME

Tags: angular, nginx

I have Angular app working under under one domain properly, but when trying to open under other domain, scripts.js and styles.css files are not loaded.

All the other files such as main.js, polyfills.js or inline.js are loaded properly.

Example of requests for comparison from nginx logs:

working:

```
1.1.1.1 - - [27/Jan/2020:18:52:25 +0100] "GET /scripts.c840c3f87f54ae7421a7.js HTTP/1.1" 200 18949 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
```

not working:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [27/Jan/2020:18:52:53 +0100] "GET /scripts.c840c3f87f54ae7421a7.js HTTP/1.1" 200 18949 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
```

And this is angular configuration:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "./build/",
            "deleteOutputPath": false,
            "baseHref" : "/",
            "deployUrl": "/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap-4-grid/css/grid.min.css",
              "src/assets/styles/main.css",
              "src/assets/styles/theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
              "node_modules/mangopay-cardregistration-js-kit/kit/mangopay-kit.js"
            ]
          },
```

What should I debug to find root cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in app was setup properly, third party CNAME service provider confirmed issues.